# Should/Must I use PDO::PARAM_NULL when binding a value that is null?

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb

When preparing an SQL query using PDO, should/must I do

```
$query->bindValue('column', $value, is_null($value) ? PDO::PARAM_NULL : PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Or I can just use `PDO::PARAM_INT` or `PDO::PARAM_STR` directly, because PDO figures that one out on its own? (as it really, really should in my opinion)

---

And as a curiosity follow-up question, if I *don't* have to use `PDO::PARAM_NULL`, what is it actually for?

Comment: It should be easy to test.  Set up a table with a nullable column, then do `INSERTs` both ways.

Comment: According to the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c) on function `really_register_bound_param` it either converts to a `long`, `boolean` and to a `string` if the value is none of those. So in a way, it kinda is obsolete to use the `PARAM::TYPE` constant, however.. if PDO is going to support another db type that does not allow for `''` to be treated as `null` in a `null` column, it's an easy change to support that database as well if you're using the param.

Comment: @RickJames Well, that's kind of why I'm asking, because it *seems* to work without it. So wondering if there's some kind of edge case or possible issues I might run into if I *don't* use it.

Comment: @Xorifelse Did a search for `PDO_PARAM_NULL` in that file, and seems to only be used once on [line 644](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L644), which is in the `fetch_value` function, so guess it's not applicable at all when binding parameters? Still not sure what's the point of it though... how would one know a value was null *before* fetching it... O.o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you do not need to use `PDO::PARAM_NULL`. If you bind NULL with any type, then PDO will use NULL internally. The value will not be converted to a string, number or any other type. NULL will remain NULL.

When you set the type to `PDO::PARAM_NULL` it is equivalent to setting the value to NULL. One might argue that `PDO::PARAM_NULL` is useless as you can achieve the same results when binding NULL with any other type.

The following statements will both bind literal NULL value.

```
$str = 'someString';
$stmt->bindParam(1, $str, PDO::PARAM_NULL); 

$str = null;
$stmt->bindParam(1, $str, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->bindValue(1, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

In *theory* PDO should recognize

```
$value = NULL;
$query->bindValue('column', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

and store a `NULL` (not the string `'NULL'`, nor `''`) into the statement.  In particular, it should be able to generate

```
UPDATE ... SET `column` = NULL;
```

from the above bind.

In that case, your code is 'overkill'.

Comment: In that case, my code actually isn't, since I'm not doing that there; only in my example here 

Answer (score 0):

The idea of PDO is that you can use 1 API to communicate to different databases and that means one might handle a value differently than the other. For example *MySQL* can handle a value of an integer type column as both an integer and a string:

```
INSERT INTO table (col_type_int) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO table (col_type_int) VALUES ('1')
```

This query would execute both ways correctly in MySQL but a different database might be more specific.

So `PDO::PARAM_TYPE` just adds another level of strictness to the query to ensure the query is translated properly for the different database types. Currently the only values that are used in the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c) are `PDO_PARAM_STR`, `PDO_PARAM_INT` and `PDO_PARAM_BOOL`. The other ones are just converted to a string.

By adding `PDO::PARAM_NULL` to the query only ensures that if you're going to use a different driver (that might not even exist yet) that handles them differently you don't need to change the code, perhaps only the query.